# Fetch request with NSMangedObject substitution in NSPredicate on child context

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm curious about the implications of crafting a predicate for an `NSFetchRequest` that includes a managed object substitution when the request is being executed on a child context.

Consider Person and Family entities. (Nevermind the reasonableness of the model or this query. I'm just curious about the details of the request):

```
...
Family *parentContextFamily = <some NSManagedObject Family>;
...
[childContext performBlock:^{
     Family *familyInChildContext = [childContext existingObjectWithID:parentContextFamily.objectID error:nil];
     NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
     request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"family = %@ AND state = %@ AND birthdate >= %@ AND birthdate <= %@",
                                 familyInChildContext,
                                 @"California",
                                 earliestDate,
                                 latestDate];
      NSArray *people = [childContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
      ...
      // do some work on people
 }];
```

Is this valid? I am executing a request on a child context substituting an `NSManagedObject` from that same context. I use this pattern regularly on main thread and background thread contexts, but I guess I have never used it in a child context.

The call to `executeFetchRequest` is crashing intermittently on the main thread with

> Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
>
> Invalid predicate: nil RHS

Apparently when this request executes on the child context in a background thread, internally, core data passes it off to the main context on the main thread. How does the `NSPredicate` represent the substituted `NSManagedObject` when it is handed off to the main context?

It's unlikely that any of the other predicate arguments is nil so I'm focusing on 'familyInChildContext'. I also realize I could potentially avoid any ambiguity by using the objects' objectIDs, but since this pattern of simply substituting the `NSManagedObject` is so convenient, I'd like to know what's happening.

Comment: What do you mean with "substitution"?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are accessing `parentContextFamily` *within* the `performBlock` of the child context (albeit only to get its `objectID`).  Try obtaining the `objectID` *before* the `performBlock` and pass only the `objectID` in.

Comment: @pbasdf You might be right. I was under the impression that -objectID was one of the few methods safe to access across threads but perhaps it's only safe to pass the obtained objectID between threads.